# Refactoring my repository from using Ardalis to only use .NET 6 library, strugling with "Linq expression could not be translated"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am refactoring a .NET 6/entity framework core 7 project which used to handle repository calls through Ardalis and Ardalis Specifications to add conditions to repository calls.

The idea of this refactoring is to only use Linq expressions and IQueryable instead of Ardalis specifications. I have a generic abstract repository class which all repositories can inherit of.

On paper, I was happy with the result and my code is compiling fine, unfortunatley when doing some tests on my API routes through Postman, I got the error : "Linq Expression  could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'"

I will show you the code I had at first:

```cs
public abstract class GenericDbContextRepository<T, TKey> : IRepository<T, TKey> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext GenericDbContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

    protected GenericDbContextRepository(DbContext DbContext)
    {
        GenericDbContext = DbContext;
        DbSet = GenericDbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var originalQuery = DbSet.AsQueryable();
        var finalQuery = originalQuery.Concat(query);
        return await finalQuery.Where(expression).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

For example, my repository "UserStoreRepository" would call FindAsync and it would pass the following IQueryable :

```cs
public static IQueryable<UserStore> GetUserStoreWithItemsQuery()
{
    IQueryable<UserStore> initialQuery = Enumerable.Empty<UserStore>().AsQueryable();
    return initialQuery
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
        .Take(1)
        .Include(UserStore => UserStore.Items);
}
```

On first try, I got the following error:

> " The Linq Expression 'EnumerableQuery{}' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'"

One of my first idea to fix this issue was simply to follow the recommendation in the error message and use AsEnumerable() in my GetUserStoreWithItemsQuery() function, I ended up with the following code:

```cs
public static IQueryable<UserStore> GetUserStoreWithItemsQuery()
{
    IQueryable<UserStore> initialQuery = Enumerable.Empty<UserStore>().AsQueryable();
    
    return initialQuery
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
        .Take(1)
        .AsQueryable()
        //Include can only be used on IQueryable, not on IEnumerable
        .Include(UserStore => UserStore.Items);
}
```

The Linq expression's translation here worked and I ended up with a new error from my  FindAsync() function :

> " The Linq Expression 'DbSet{}' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'"

I thought of applying the same fix with AsEnumerable():

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var originalQuery = DbSet.AsEnumerable();
    var finalQuery = originalQuery.Concat(query.AsEnumerable());
    return await finalQuery.AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
}
```

But now I have the following error :

> The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

I probably could "bypass" and implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' but I feel like I should not have to, I am guessing there must be a better and cleaner way to achieve what I am trying to, and I am starting to think switching to Enumerable then back to IQueryable is probably not the good way of doing things, whether for code/database call performance and code quality. I welcome any advices and fixes.

Thank you all.

Comment: What query are you using? When using IQueryable you need to make sure it can be translated to SQL.

Comment: @MaxNaumov Hello, I am using the query returned by my function "GetUserStoreWithItemsQuery()". That's it, not adding anything to it.

Comment: EF Core tries to convert your query into SQL. EF Core can't translate `Enumerable.Empty<UserStore>()` into SQL.

Comment: @GuruStron any idea then how I could refactor my Function? Also I have a second Error where they can't translate DbSet<UserStore>, the error is written in my post

Comment: I do not understand what this code do. Transforming `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable` is wrong. EF translates only `IQueryable` produced from `DbSet`.

Comment: Whatever you mean by "Ardalis", it's not part of EF Core, LINQ or SQL. It's the handle of an author. EF Core **doesn't need* a low-level CRUD class named "repository" over it either. A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is *already* a single-entity Repository. Explain what you're actually trying to do, not how you think it needs to be implemented. Using EF and LINQ is actually quite simple. The code you posted is ... convoluted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose that it some of the packages by [Steve Smith](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture), for example the  [Specification](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification) one.

Comment: Are you trying to load the latest User? `var user=await _context.Users.OrderByDescending(u=>u.Created).FirstAsync();` If you want to filter, just add a `Where` call. You **don't** need an extra `FindAsync`.

Comment: @GuruStron I know very well who the author is. I was being kind, trying to avoid mentioning this is the source of most "repository" questions and bugs at SO

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will probably end up using the code you provided, maybe create a separate function for this use case.

I know I ended up with a convoluted code, I was trying to keep my generic repository as abstract and flexible as possible. I am going to take all advices into account and build something.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I think, in your particular case, the `FindAsync` method could be similar to this one, please take a look:

```cs
public virtual Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAsync(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null,
    CancellationToken token = default,
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> dbQuery = _dbSet.AsNoTracking();

    if (predicate != null)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(predicate);
    }

    return await navigationProperties
        .Aggregate(dbQuery, (current, navigationProperty) => current.Include(navigationProperty))
        .ToListAsync(token);
}
```

Comment: Hi Denis, 

I like the code you provided, but to be able to use it I would need to use "params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties" instead of an IQueryable right? I would need to create a navigationProperties's instance with the same conditions as in my function GetUserStoreWithItemsQuery(), is that correct ? not used to manipulate "params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]"

Comment: Hi @Dodge, you can use it this way: `await _repository.FindAsync(x => x.CreationDate.Equals(DateTime.Now)), token, x => x.Items);`. I am including the navigation property using this expression: `x => x.Items`.